# How do I create an error message if process is not found in C#?

Tags: c#

Here is an example of what I wrote:

```
string Proc = "minecraft://";

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(Proc);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `try-catch` statement for you to know the exception or error that will appear on your code.

```
try
{
    Process.Start(Proc);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```